# Tem como clicar em uma <TD> e pegar o valor de outra <TD> hide?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

Uma  com 4 , sendo uma hide. Há como eu fazer um click em qualquer  e pegar o valor da está hide e enviar para a minha controller? Dessa forma eu pego o valor da está sendo clicada.

```
$('#nmUsuario').on("dblclick", '.clique', function () {
    CarregaDados($(this).text());
})

function CarregaDados(ajaxParameter) {

    $.ajax({

        url: '/CadastroAcesso/CarregaDadosPagina',
        datatype: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify({ _nivel: ajaxParameter }),
        success: function (data) {
        },
        error: function (error) {
        }
    })
}
```

Agora, como eu clico nessa `<TD>` e pego o valor da que está hide. Eu acho que deveria pegar oi valor da `<TR>`, fazer um each e carregar apenas o valor da `<TD>` hide, mas estou apanhando nisso. Como percorrer a `<TR>` para pegar a `<TD>` que eu quero.

Estive fora por um tempo e agora voltei para terminar o que eu comecei. Continua dando erro. Ele não entra no sucesso do `ajax`, ao contrário, ele entra na função `Error` do `ajax`.

Comment: Talvez só consigas fazer indo buscar a td por id ou pelo name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi assim:

```
$(this).parent().find(".idusuario").text()
```

Answer (score 0):

Digamos que a sua TD escondida tem nome:

```
<td class="escondida" style="display:none;">Valor escondido</td>
```

Então basta alterar o seu código para:

```
$('#nmUsuario').on("dblclick", '.clique', function () {
    CarregaDados($(this).find(".escondida").text());
});
```

Não testei no jfiddle mas caso não dê certo dê uma olhadinha no comando find do jquery, ele vai resolver pra vc.

Comment: Tá vindo vazio. A tbody da table é montada dinamicamente via jquery. Será que isso não afeta?

Comment: Se a chamada do script está acontecendo antes da criação aí sim afetaria. Teria como vc adicionar um fiddle do seu código ou então colocar ele ali na sua pergunta pra ver se a gente consegue caminhar mais na solução?

Comment: Fiz uma edição no post para mostrar em que pé ainda estou.

Answer (score 0):

Use o seletor :not(:visible)

```
var conteudoHtmlTd = $("td:not(:visible)").html(); //se quiser o html da td
var conteudoTextoTd = $("td:not(:visible)").text(); //se quiser so o texto da td
```

Se você quiser pegar uma td hide que está na mesma linha que uma outra td que você clicou ficaria assim:

```
$(document).on("click", "td", function(){
    var conteudoHtmlTd = $(this).parent().find("td:not(:visible)").html();
});
```

Caso ela tenha uma classe fica mais facil ainda:

```
$(document).on("click", "td", function(){
    var conteudoHtmlTd = $(this).parent().find(".classe").html();
});
```